# Ping latency to the router?

Tags: networking, router, ping

Since i am french i mean by 'Box': the router that connect to internet... When launching a ping to the box i get on 30 ping responce time pratically 1 to 2 MS each ping. But sometime it up to 20 MS. All this with a câbled CAT 5 câble and a Gigabyte ethernet switch... Is it ok or i can have problems playing games or downloading files. Should i switch to tri-band WiFi like: https://store.netgear.fr/product/rbke963-100eus
Thanks...

Comment: 20ms seems a bit much to just ping the router, that should really be more like 1ms. Doubt it will cause problems for gaming though, really depends on the full route towards whichever gaming server you use. What is your question exactly? Are you experiencing ping issues right now?

Comment: Wifi will always be worse than cabled connections. How often is "sometimes"? If it is a single 20ms packet among 100 then you probably won't notice it, if it is every packet then you *might* notice it. For reference a 60Hz monitor refreshes at 16ms intervals so 20ms is maybe 1 frame of lag. That's ignoring your ping to the rest of the world...

Comment: Hi. Mokubai and MIG. The ping spike of 20MS appear after a lot of pings... But there is a somme 2MS spike and a little of 4MS nearly...

Answer (score 0):

The ping roundtrip time depends on a lot of influences, such as the network (sloppy cabling, bad switch, ...) but also on the CPU load of the pinged device.

With many "boxes" (not only in France) have I seen their CPU running at 90%+ if they serve a handfull of connections running highly interleaved packet flows. This does show up in much higher ping roundtrip times and especially in very uneven distributions.

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting...